# Windows 2008 R2 Task Schduler is raising the following error “0x41301”

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, scheduled-task, windows-command-prompt, task-scheduler

I  have a console application which uses some SharePoint dll libraries, to execute a background jobs. now I can manually run the console application without any problem. but when I schedule its execution using windows 2008 R2 Task Scheduler, I got the following error:-
0x41301

now here is how the action looks like:-

[image]

and I have the following text inside the Add arguments :-

```
-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\batchfiles\ConsoleApplication1.exe
```

so can anyone advice why I am getting this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It indicates the app is already running. Here it is an article described the ways to solve this: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/82c22050-38b7-4612-a3e2-81d897687fac/task-scheduling-on-windows-2008-with-error-code-0x41301?forum=winservergen 
Just a quick recap: try to specify "Start In" value

Comment: what do I need to add in the Start in ?? thanks

Comment: As far as I understood, all the related files to the task are stored in the C:\batchfiles\ folder. So I would try to specify the path to this folder in there.

Comment: @batistita09 did not work

Comment: there might be an issue with permissions also. have u checked if the user belongs to the "log on as batch job" group?

Comment: @batistita09 yes he is , and also using the same user I have scheduled many tasks to call .bat files,, but now I want to run .exe files,, which is not working